# Clone form contents, change attribute, append to form in jQuery or vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I'm trying to achieve as above - I got as far as I could, but the code does not execute at all.

```
$('.container').on('click', 'form', function() {
  var clone = $('form').clone();
  clone.find('input').attr('name', 'pick0' + length);
  $('form').appendChild(clone);
});
```

html + js example on codepen
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KQrEMd

Edit:

Trying to copy a form based on a click of the form. 1 click = 1 extra form.

Comment: are you trying to get the content of the form ?

Comment: One issue is the use of appendChild. appendChild is a vanilla js method. In jQuery to can use append() instead.

Comment: @ArashKiani no, just copying the form so there would be two forms

Comment: _.appendChild_ doesn't exist in jQuery. Are you maybe looking for _.append()_?. Also note that that next clones will also have the previously inserted elements. I'm not sure what you're trying to do so please specify. This is too broad

Comment: append() is correct, thanks but it only works for 1 click, next click will copy two forms, and another will copy four etc... which is not what I am after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
$('.container').on('click', 'form', function() {
  var clone = $('form:last').clone();
  length = $('form').length;
  clone.find('input').attr('name', 'pick' + length);
  $('.container').append(clone);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('.container').on('click', 'form', function() {
    if(typeof($('form').data('length')=='undefined')){
       var $length = 1;
    }else{
      var $length = parseInt($('form').data('length'));
    }
  var clone = $('form').clone();
  clone.find('input').attr('name', 'pick0' + $length);
  $('form').append(clone.html());
  $('form').data('length',$length+1);
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly perhaps this can help

```
$('.container').on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target.pick0.value);
  var input = e.target.pick0.cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].appendChild(input);
});
```